# Group of fields for different group of users

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field, registration, joomla-user-groups

I have custom field "Client type" in registration form, which I created in Users->Fields. Already I have next usergroups:

1. Registered
2. Subgroup of Registered - Human
3. Subgroup of Registered - Company

I need to register user in certain group, depends of value in radiobuttons group from this field.

I think to expand this question (I coudn't found a lot of information about custom fields for users). How to create fields for only one group of users?

Answer (score 1):

Before registration, any visitor will be a guest, so it does not make sense to create custom fields for different user groups in the registration form.

But if you want to assign the user group after registration based on the value of the radio button field, this can't be done without a 3rd party extension.

Comment: ...  a 3rd party extension ... or custom plugin designed for this exact purpose.

Comment: of course, a custom plugin is implicitly included in the 3rd party extension expression.

Comment: Thanks, I found the 3rd party plugin for my purposes.